# TYPO3 can't display the Backend

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

So I set up TYPO3 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 and I downloaded PHP 7.2.15. After I updated the PHP version the whole backend broke.

Here is my System:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
- TYPO3 CMS 8.7.6
- PHP 7.2.15
- MYSQL 5.5.60

When I log in with my password at http://myurl.com/typo3/
it simply sais this:

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
#1476107295: PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /var/www/typo3/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/ViewHelpers/CountViewHelper.php line 67
```

Here is also a screenshot of my error page:

[image]

What should i do?

I only have TemplaVoila+ installed.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encountered this issue: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82227

Solve it like this:

1. Update your TYPO3 Core to the latest TYPO3 8 Version (currently 8.7.24)
2. replace TYPO3 8.7.6 Core with 8.7.24, then access http://myurl.com/typo3/install (install tool) and execute the update-wizard
3. check if PHP 7.2 is working now as this should also update "typo3fluid" (https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid)

This should fix your problem.
For the future: always upDATE at TYPO3 asap. With upGRADES you can wait untill all extensions are compatible as TYPO3 supports LTS Versions quiet long :)

Answer (score 0):

try to run the install tool (as stand alone).

clear all caches.

check for broken extensions.

do system checks.

otherwise: disable all extensions in your PackageStates.php one after the other until your system is running again (of course: start with non core extensions, start from the end)